# Pinout difference

Tags: gpio

On a Rpi2, `gpio readall` output:

[image: ASCII graphic of gpio readall program output]

Seems completely different from this image (on [elinux.org](http://elinux.org/File:Pi-GPIO-header.png)):

[image: Diagram of RPi B+ and 2 GPIO pinout]

What am I missing?

Comment: GPIO notation in 2nd image translates to BCM column in the first image. While Name column is same as Wiring pi numbering.

Comment: I am totally confused.

Comment: I've edited (cropped and reposted) the original first image - so it is now much more readable IMHO.

Comment: The image and the `gpio` output do correspond.  Look at the two sides, which in the `gpio` chart are divided dead center (the "physical" column breaks the chart in half).  At the top you have *3.3 V, 5 V*.  Next you have *SDA 1, 5V*, and so on down to *0V, GPIO 21*.  Here "0V" and ground (GND) are synonymous, and some of the pins have multiple functions and thus two names.  SDA 1 is also GPIO 2, GPIO 21 is also a serial clock line (SCLK) for a SPI interface (which requires three pins, MOSI, MISO, SCLK).

Answer (score 4):

The table from `gpio readall` all is very complete and accurate. The interpretation is as follows.
Looking from the top, connector on your right, numbers are odd on the left, even on the right, the square on the PCB is pin '1'.

```
column 'physical'  40 pin connector position.
column 'v'         current value
column 'mode'      current mode In/Out GPIO.setup(n, GPIO.OUT)
column 'name'      human description/function 
column 'wPI'       Wiring Pi (*) pin id, GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
column 'BCM'       BCM pin Id. GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
```

[* Wiring PI](http://wiringpi.com/pins/)

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is what you are getting at but compare the elinux image with the name and physical columns in the GPIO readall output. The readall output also includes the BCM numbering scheme (the actual chip that runs the Pi) and the wiringpi (a library used to access the GPIO pins) numbering scheme. The readall output also includes the pin mode (input or output)  and its current value (high 1 or low 0). This thread https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=101926 contains more info on the various pin naming schemes.exactly

Comment: For example GPIO7 seems in COMPLETELY different places.

Comment: Because of the numbering scheme.

Comment: I don't quite understand how the numbering scheme maps...

Comment: @hendry Hold the board so that the SD card end is at the top. Then look at the read all output, each row corresponds to one row of 2 pins. If you divide the table in to down the center. the left half of the table corresponds to the left column of pins on the board and the right side of the table the right column of pins. So looking at the first row of the table you have pins (physical) 1 and 2, and so on down the board until pin 26 or 40 (depending on the board you have).

Comment: @hendry If you look at row 6 (physical pins 11 and 12 on the board) that  corresponds to (BCM calls this) pin 17 and 18 (as indicated by the first and last columns). Likewise, the wiringpi library calls these pins 0 and 1. Think about it like a foreign language in English we have one and two, in French we call it uno and deux, and in Spanish uno and dos. They all mean the same thing,

Comment: Maybe my brain is switched off, but I still don't understand. Is there a image showing how these pins map maybe? For the elinux graphic, 17 is 3x3V and 18 is GPIO24. How come ?!?!

Comment: @hendry It is because the image is using the BCM scheme look at the corresponding row (9) of the readall output, The readall output is showing all three schemas (physical, bcm and wiring pi) the elinux image is showing only (bcm) and, although not explicitly listing the physical numbers by kabelking the first and last rows of pins (pin 1 and 2) at the top and (pin 39 and 40) at the bottom.

Comment: @hendry Most libraries will allow you to determine which pin naming schema you want to use to identify a pin. See this question for example http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40067/using-bcm-gpio-pin-numbers-with-wiringpi-c-library/40068#40068

Comment: @hendry Put bluntly, it does not matter what the reason for these patterns is from a user perspective.  I would guess it has to do with the way the pins are numbered on the actual chip, and that the way the lines end up on the breakout has to do with logistics on the board.  So yes, they seem to have no rhyme or reason.  But it does not matter as long as you understand there are two different numbering schemes used in code, and neither of them corresponds to the ordering on the physical breakout.